# Flutter SplashScreen Image not appearing

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a Flutter splash screen where an image is supposed to show up but it never does. When i add a color that works so i know the package was used correctly.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  sqflite: ^2.2.7
  intl: ^0.18.1
  flutter_slidable: ^3.0.0
  flutter_slidable_list_view: ^1.2.8
  favorite_button: ^0.0.4
  jiffy: ^6.1.0
  activity_ring: ^0.3.0
  quickalert: ^1.0.1
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.19
 
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1


flutter_native_splash: 
  android: true
  ios: true
  web: false
  background_image: assets/images/logo.png


flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: assets/images/logo.png
 
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/logo.png
```

Also for some reason when i open the image in vscode at the top it says read only. I also tested my path to the image using a widget it is correct and I ran the 3 termianl commands you are supposed to run (imge is 512x512 size)

Comment: Share code for better understanding

Comment: check the path of the file

Comment: I confirmed the path is correct

Comment: whats the android version of the device you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `image: ...`

example :

```
flutter_native_splash: 
  android: true
  ios: true
  web: false
  image: assets/images/logo.png
```

and run `flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create` in terminal